# Why can't I confirm that one of the solutions worked for me?

Tags: discussion

Why can't I comment and thank Max C to tell him that his answer fixed my problem.  I took the battery and card out, tried to focus again and it worked!  Thank you, Max C!

Answer (score 3):

Carol, you can confirm simply by voting the answer up, which you can do when you have a very little bit of positive interaction on the site. This is pretty easy to do, simply by asking a question of your own or providing a helpful answer to an unanswered question — existing users will vote it up. See more on this [in the site help](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

You don't need to comment. In fact, unless you have something substantial to add, it's better to not to. The goal of this site is to focus on the questions and answers directly, without extra chit-chat.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mattdm's response:

For questions which you have asked yourself, there should be a tick mark next to the answer that you can tick to signify that "this is the answer that help you the most".

It is over here
      ||
      ||
<==

Comment: I think that Carol wants to comment to affirm that an answer to someone else's question also worked for her.

Comment: @mattdm It appears so.